# Outlook create folders - basic setup and approach

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, directory, cdo.message

What are the proper project references (.NET or COM or otherwise) and downloads I need to program using Visual Studio 2010 C# so I can programmatically create 1,000 folders and rules in an Outlook users mailbox?

I have tried CDO but it appears to be way out of date and very hard to use now.

Comment: Just added a VSTO to Excel for a customer. It worked pretty well for the most part. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh128768.aspx

Comment: @Calon hey man please, stop doing this with tags... If you edit the post, fix it, arrange it, not just change one tag for another very similar

Answer (score 0):

1000 folders and rules seems complicated - is this against an Outlook PST or an Exchange mailbox?

I digress. CDO / CDONTS is obsolete (but easy enough to use in COM, in my opinion). The current API documentation and advice is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652780.aspx

Assuming you used the installation defaults for Office and VS you should find interop assemblies in your system somewhere - just reference them in your project and have some fun.

Comment: You can also get the interops from MS website somewhere as well.